# Open a file from the parent folder

Tags: html, file, hyperlink

Is it possible to open a file from the parent folder?

lets say I have this file tree

```
parent
    other
        file.pdf
    website
        index.html
```

and I wanted to open file.pdf from index using the `a` tag, how would I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: If you just want a link to download the file, just use "../other/file.pdf" in the A tag. But if you are looking for embed a pdf file, then consult here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "special instruction" `..` to traverse "up" a directory level:

```
<a href="../other/file.pdf">file.pdf</a>
```

It can be repeated multiple times to continue traverse up the folder hierarchy.

Comment: New there was something double in there. I haven't used it in ages see

Answer (score 1):

Use double dot to go one level up:

```
<a href="../other/file.pdf">file.pdf</a>
```

Comment: New there was something double in there. I haven't used it in ages see

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply give the full path in the href

```
<a href="../other/file.pdf">link</a>
```