# How to use <img src > in google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I want to display the image in a google apps script using src attribute. I put the folder id and the path. But the image couldn't display.  I shared the folder here.

Thank you for your help!

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByNw-B9nXMcbMkxHTGt2X2xUTzQ

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
    .setTitle('picture').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  return html;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p> Dispaly picture </p>
    <p><img src="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByNw-B9nXMcbMkxHTGt2X2xUTzQ/200w.gif"> </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SandboxMode.IFRAM is now the only support mode. NATIVE and emulated modes have both been depreciated for two years.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `img src=""` requires the URL of the actual image you want to display, not the folder that contains it. To get the correct link you need to open the picture in its own window or click share and get the link that way.

The correct link for your image is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByNw-B9nXMcbSTN2S2ZiYWprdzA/view

To use this in the src you need to add the fileID to the end of this format URL:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=

So it becomes:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0ByNw-B9nXMcbSTN2S2ZiYWprdzA

NOTE: The drive file must be shared with 'anyone with the link' for other users to be able to view the file or for use outside of G Suite.

Comment: The perfect solution. Thank you!

Comment: This did **not** work for me when deploying the web app using a regular google account. It **did** work when deploying the web app from my google account in my company's GSuite.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the accepted answer from James Donnellan did not work for me. When I publish the page, I can see the image but others can not.
I checked the sharing settings and also tried to publish with the "execute as me" option. Tried with given link too, same results.

Though the method mentioned above is much more simple to use, I would like to share what worked for me in case someone else is experiencing same problems. I used converting the image to bytes:

In App Script:

```
function loadImageBytes(){
var id = "your_drive_file_id"
var bytes = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes();
return Utilities.base64Encode(bytes);
}
```

In Javascript

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler( function(bytes){ showImage(bytes) })
.loadImageBytes();

function showImage(bytes){
document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + bytes; 
}
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: This did the trick for me thanks so much!  Although on my end I wasn't even able to see the images I was requesting until adding this workaround.  Do you happen to know why simply referencing the image with src="sharable_link" from a shared folder doesn't do the trick?  Hoping maybe there might be something you leaned since August that is escaping me.

Comment: For me the other answer also didn't work when using a regular google account to deploy the app. It did work when deploying from my company's gsuite account.