# Using Imported Fonts in a Google App

Tags: html, css, cors, font-face

I am creating a web app using Google Apps Script. When I wanted to import a photo from Google Docs, I followed the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43843917/how-to-use-img-src-in-google-apps-script) and it worked perfectly. I thought a similar process would work for using a custom font hosted on Docs, but it throws a CORS exception.

The relevant code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    src: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1r2a5nd6om75url39428dfju4");
} 

#headBanner {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
}
```

```html
<div id="headBanner"> 
  <p>This text should be in MyCustomFont</p>
</div>
```

The error it throws is: "Access to Font at '[URL in font]' from origin '[Google Script page I'm using]' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '[Google Script page I'm using]' is therefore not allowed access."

How could I fix this? I just find it perplexing that it would throw a CORS exception for the font file but not for the picture.

Comment: What I find perplexing is that, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" for images is allowed by default and needs to be specifically turned off if you don't want your images to be displayed by other domains. I still haven't found a reasonable explanation for this exception. For any other type of files, including font-files or stylesheets, unless they're allowed for all or for the specific domain you requesting the resource for, they access is not allowed. But you can always access the resource (or download it), save it to your own server and you'll be able to load it from there. *Can*, not ***may***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font files, along with AJAX requests using fetch are the only things that use CORS. Image requests and static inline requests for JavaScript (via  tags) and CSS do not invoke CORS.

In this case, there is nothing you can do, short of (as @andrei-gheorghiu suggests) downloading the font file manually, saving it to your server and then accessing it from there. Whilst you *can* do that **technically**, it would *technically* be **stealing**. Hence his use of "Can, not may"...

Fun fact - CORS was basically invented for the **specific** use-case you've come across - so that 'font factories' could design fonts (which cost them money, obviously) and then be able to allow/deny access to those font files, depending on whether you have paid a license fee.

No doubt not the answer you wanted, but the answer nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I believe I'm going to use a google font instead.

Comment: Probably wise - I've never seen much benefit to using specific, licensed fonts - but then, I've always been focused on function, not form - as long as I can read it, it's good :)