# "Failed to load PDF document" HTML5 Object

Tags: html, pdf

I am trying to display some PDF documents on my webpage, but I keep getting `Failed to load PDF document` in my browser. I have tried it in both Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox (both latest versions). Whenever I inspect the object, and I open the src url directly in my browser, the path is correct and it downloads the PDF file.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<object data="https://example.com/_f/user/pdf/my_file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
  <p>Alternative text</p>
</object>
```

---

### Update

I have found an [solution here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser) that I have used. Works great!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and had to change the`Content-Disposition attachment` header.

I changed:

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"`

TO

`Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"`

See also: [How to force files to open in browser instead of download (pdf)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293893/how-to-force-files-to-open-in-browser-instead-of-download-pdf)

Comment: That did it! Thanks!  I've been at this for hours till I found your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with your url. can you try with this path?

```
<object data="http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/pdf_creation_apis_and_specs/PDFOpenParameters.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100px" height="100%">
  <p>Alternative text</p>
</object>
```

Comment: That only shows me the alternate text, meaning the file is not correct?

Comment: Try to navigate to the link using your browser. Is it working?

Comment: try TYPE="application/x-pdf"