# Embed pdf to website, hide the link and display pdf directly

Tags: html, wordpress, pdf

I want to add a pdf to my blog post. I found the following code on stackoverflow to add the link.

```
<embed src="https://mypdflink" type=""application/pdf" width="600" height="400">
```

This code adds a link to the pdf, which is good. But what I really want is to display the pdf on the blog page, without showing the link or asking readers to click to open the pdf. Can anyone please help me?

By the way, this is my first time building my own blog/website. I have no background in website building or computer science in general. I am using free theme on wordpress.com. I appreciate your suggestion and help!

Comment: Content that requires a plugin such as Adobe Acrobat require user interaction to open said files, it's a security feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display PDF within web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me, hope it helps. :)

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<embed src="http://www.dol.wa.gov/forms/420001.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="400" height="600"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. The codes didn't work for me. But I found another way, explained in my answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help. I ended up not using any html code. The pdf I wanted to insert was a dashboard made in Tableau consisting of a graph and table. What I ended up doing was that I took a screenshot of the pdf, pasted it to painter.net, resized the photo to 300dpi, and inserted the photo to my wordpress post....:)