# Unable to return file in mvc4 and jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am trying to download file in mvc4. Below is my code to download the file. I am making ajax request to get file. My controller code looks like fine. variable result will get required bytes. I am having trouble with success gfunction in Download function in jquery. control will not come to success function. Even my alert is not working. Am i missing anything in the above code? Can someone please suggest me?

```
 public ActionResult Download(int? ClientId)
        {
            service.Service objService = new service.Service();
            DashboardBAL objdb = new DashboardBAL();
            string filepath = objdb.GetFilepath(ClientId.GetValueOrDefault(0));
            string folderName = @"F:\UploadedFile";
            string serverMappath = (folderName);
             byte[] result = objService.DownloadFileFromDMS(filepath);
            string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);
            string FileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
            {
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath),
                Inline = true,
            };
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(serverMappath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(serverMappath);
            }
            string strdocPath = serverMappath + @"\" + FileName;
            if (result != null)
            {
                FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                objfilestream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
                objfilestream.Close();
            }
            return File(result, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, FileName);
        }


function Download(pClientid) {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            data: { ClientId: pClientid },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("Download", "TestRendering")',
           // url: '/TestRendering/Download',
            headers: {
                'VerificationToken': forgeryId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(1);
                ShowFiepopup(data);
            }
        });
    }


function ShowFiepopup(FileName) {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: "Preview of " + FileName,
            width: 850,
            height: 600,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },

            open: function () {
                var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" Zoom=\"100%\" width=\"800px\" height=\"600px\">";
                object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href=\"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                object += "</object>";
                object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "../UploadedFile/" + FileName);
                $("#dialog").html(object);

            }
        });
    };


function Download(pClientid) {
        var fileUrl = '@Url.Action("Download", "TestRendering",new {ClientID= "pClientid" })';
        alert(fileUrl);
        fileUrl = fileUrl.replace("_X_", fileName);
        ShowFiepopup(fileUrl)
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem..Is the action method throwing any error?

Comment: No it is not returning anything. I have Jquery functioncalled Download. In success block i am not getting anything. Even i put one alert and it is also not working

Comment: Have you looked at you Network tab in the debugger console. What is the response that you get back?\

Comment: Thank you. It is not returning anything. Status 200

Comment: In success function control is not coming because i put one test alert and it is also not working. Can someone tell me my jquey function and controller is correct? My action method is actionresult should i need to change this? Thanks

Comment: How about showing the error, as in error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not download the file using ajax request, if you want to preview the file, then update the code that opens the dialog and set the `FileName` to the 
URL for the file itself

```
function Download(pClientid) {
    var fileUrl = '@Url.Action("Download", "TestRendering",new {ClientID="_X_"})';
    fileUrl = fileUrl.replace ("_X_",fileName)
    ShowFiepopup(fileUrl)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. when i put alert fileUrl  will hold /testrendering/download/2392. In the above code my control is not going back to controller simply it will display filurl.

Comment: see the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser 
basically you will replace the src attribute with the url for the file

Comment: Yes i agree. Lets say my url is F:\UploadedFile\1007\1007_20160930093052693_2745c7a9-3a60-4d78-b2b2-5b0b885a3d7b.pdf But when i host this application and when i access the application from other systems How it will work?

Comment: In this case your controller action will convert this URL to be: http://yourserver/TestRendering/Download/1232