# PDFs in Amazon S3 don't open in Chrome for view

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a website which is developed in PHP and hosted in amazon server. PDF files that are uploaded in server are not opening for view in chrome browser but this pdf file is opening in other browser (internet explorer) for viewing. In chrome it is downloaded. I want this pdf to be open for viewing. code for link is

```
<a href="<?php echo $filename;?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $data['File_Label'];?></a>
```

URL: [Please click here](http://idtc-icai.s3.amazonaws.com/download/3.%20Collated%20Suggestions%20submitted%20on%20Draft%20Rules.pdf)

But below file is opening for viewing in chrome [Please check this](http://idtc-icai.s3.amazonaws.com/download/the_constitution_2016.pdf)

Comment: How this question is relevant to the `php` tag?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en-GB

Comment: Same problem with opera. If other link like http://ozlabs.org/~dgibson/papers/dtc-paper.pdf open in the browser, the problem is probably the "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" HTTP header. Don't know a solution

Comment: @DanielAlder Look its an anchor tag that is being used

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the question is not related to chrome - no browser will open the file as "pdf" if the content-type header is not set correctly to pdf.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser

Comment: @Dekel Then surley the servers mime.types should cope with that

Comment: @RiggsFolly, not exactly - when using S3 - you set the mime-type when uploading the file to the S3 (if not - the default octet-stream is used). You can set the correct mime-type while uploading, or afterwards. Updated my answer, you can check.

Comment: @YugalKishorBais, How do you upload the files to S3?

Comment: @Dekel: by AWS SDK [code is  $s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $sub_bucket.$actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ) ] where $tmp= Temp Name, $bucket= S3 Bucket name, $actual_image_name= Original file name

Comment: http://idtc-icai.s3.amazonaws.com/download/the_constitution_2016.pdf this file is opening for viewing in chrome. please check

Comment: In my chrome it downloads it and not open for view.

Comment: Can you add a link to the SDK you are using? I can't find this function in the sdk provided by aws.

Comment: @Dekel: http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation  please see this

Comment: Answer updated, you can check

Comment: And you can add the `php` tag back :)

Comment: @Dekel: Thanks, I used $s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $sub_bucket.$actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,array(),'application/pdf'); and it is working now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want the browser to treat the file as pdf you should let him know that his file is a pdf. The way to do so is to send the relevant header:

```
Content-type: application/pdf
```

The current header that is sent by `s3` is:

```
Content-type: application/octet-stream
```

Since you upload the files to s3 - you can either set the correct mime-type for the file during uploading or afterward, using some of the s3 tools (for example s3cmd for windows).

According to the [link to the documentation](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation) you provided, the `putObjectFile` function is deprecated, but this is the definition:

```
putObjectFile (string $file, string $bucket, string $uri, [constant $acl = S3::ACL_PRIVATE], [array $metaHeaders = array()], [string $contentType = null])
```

As you can see - the last parameter is `contentType` - so you can set it to `application/pdf` when uploading the file.
This will set the correct header when downloading.

Comment: Look its an anchor tag that is being used

Comment: @Dekel PDF link is created in index page and it is simple html anchor tag. how do I put content-type for that particular link.

Comment: This is not related to the html - the header is something that the server is sending.

Comment: Now that I like much better UV, and I learnt something about S3 too, thanks

Comment: Will appreciate to know from the down-voter why did I get a down vote on the answer!

Comment: Probably @AjayThakur being spiteful because someone downvoted his answer, and it probably was not even you that did it

Comment: Wasn't me. @AjayThakur - if the downvote was yours I would appreciate an explanation here.