# SpringBoot - display PDF-file in browser instead of downloading

Tags: java, spring-boot

i am trying to display a pdf in my browser with spring. my problem is that the browser downloads the file instead of displaying it. this is my code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/download" , method=RequestMethod.GET , produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPdf() throws IOException {
    ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("TMOBILE.pdf");
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));

}
```

i am looking forward to your answers! thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display PDF within web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser)

Answer (score 3):

Change your headers to this:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

Setting the Content-Type to `application/octet-stream` will FORCE it to always download.

Answer (score 0):

Use Content-Type `application/pdf` instead of `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score -1):

Combining your code & Andrew answer above this modified code works fine !!

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPdf() throws IOException {
         ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("files/Locations.pdf");
         return ResponseEntity
                 .ok()
                 .contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
                 .header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + pdfFile.getFilename() + "\"")
                 .contentType(
                         MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
                 .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));

     }
```