# In Pdf file "Alt text on image" not displayed on browser

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, alt

I have Atl text in my pdf file while opening in acrobat reader, but same not displaying in web browser either if it is embedded view or via pdf.js,
I almost tried everything every plugin,
How can i implement this in my project is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Try with title attribute.

Comment: it render dynamically according to input(PDF file) every time, how can i use title tag for Alt Text is there any object which i need to access for this?

Comment: Try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser

Comment: For your above Suggestion  : this is the question where all suggestions are going to "How we can render pdf in our webpage", but i am asking "How we can display alt text on over an image after online rendered pdf".

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: Please understand my question "How should Web browsers render alternate text in pdf"

Comment: Here is the code:
`code`
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>PPT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http://s3.amazonaws.com/lms_s3/1/client_assets/ppt/PA6E-C01-PPT.pdf' width='100%' height='600px' frameborder='0'></iframe> 
</body>
</html>
`code`