# How can I preview a PDF,DOCX, PPTX file directly in my browser? can you suggest me in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I preview a PDF,DOCX, PPTX  file directly in my browser? I need to Preview the PDF, DOCX, PPTX files in directly through the Browser. for example, The attachment in the gmail we can directly preview any type of file. Like that example i need to implement. Can you suggest me how to do? Instead of IFrame I want to use different approch

Comment: Please refer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/13378146) for DOC[X]/PPT[X]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the browsers to make the PDF previewing work, please refer [PDF](https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-knowledge/view-pdf-in-browser.html).

And you can also use `iFrame` in code to preview office files, please check [OFFICE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27958186/13378146) as my comments above. And [PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4854037/13378146)