# How do I display a PDF that is getting returned from an api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I'm working on a JavaScript/React project and I have a GET endpoint that when I hit returns back a PDF. I am able to hit the endpoint successfully and am getting back a 200 success back but the response I'm getting back looks like something along the lines of....

%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (��) /Creator(��) /Producer(��)....

Does anyone know how I can take this and turn it into the PDF file in a separate window or popup? All the solutions I have found are requiring me to have a pdf url or file to do this. I'm completely new to this and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You are forcing the browser to show binary information as text, most probably due to wrong content-type header. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236017) or use a js plugin like [pdf.js by mozilla](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)(will work even if a browser doesn't have an inbuit viewer).

Answer (score 0):

If you set the return content type to "application/pdf", your browser should display it correctly I think. How you set the content type depends on what you're using server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you also develop the API, setting [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) and [Content-Type hader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) , it will be perfect.

Also do not use a button that call a fetch to the url, just use a link, a real  not the react router Link

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to send your PDF file from the endpoint as base64 URI so you can Download the file or just open it in your browser, your API should respond something link this :

```
echo "data:application/pdf;base64,".base64_encode($YourFileHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Html keep one div which is used to display

```
    <div id="pdfViewer"></div>
Below is script
<script>
    function getPdf() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/api/Data', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        xhr.onload = function () {
            debugger;
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                displayPdf(xhr.response);
            } else {
                console.log('Failed to load PDF');
            }
        };

        xhr.send();
    }

    function displayPdf(data) {
        var container = document.getElementById('pdfViewer');
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var embed = document.createElement('embed');
        embed.src = url;
        embed.type = 'application/pdf';
        embed.width = '100%';
        embed.height = '600px';
        container.appendChild(embed);
    }
    getPdf();
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).