# How to display PDF from Byte Array inside of <embed> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, embed

Hey guys I am new at Front End Development. I want to display my pdf file from byte array like:

```
<embed id="preview_pdf" src=' +myitem + "?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0" +  ' frameborder="0" oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false" allowfullscreen >' + '</embed>');
```

how it is possible for me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display PDF within web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853898/display-pdf-within-web-browser)

Comment: Sadly no since im getting my pdf file as byte array and want to display that pdf file from database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Adobe Embed API](https://opensource.adobe.com/pdfembed-sdk-docs/) can be used to display PDF files in modern browsers and can accept a Promise that resolves to an array buffer as input. The important part of the code might look like this...

```
adobeDCView.previewFile({
    content: { promise: Promise.resolve(buffer) }
    metaData: { fileName: :"myFile.pdf" }
});
```

It's free.